# Lua: match string but ignore same string if it matches between double columns

Tags: lua, string-matching

I have a string like this:

```
hello item:::::405498:::244405553::3405:34:405:59:::445:447:3205:::[test] and another 405 with test
```

I need to catch the last part of the string ignoring `:` as delimiter.

In my specific case I need to find the last `405` ignoring the `:405498:` `:244405553:` `:3405:` and `:405:` that comes first

I'm really rookie with Lua and so far I have tried to match with `:(.-):` but I think I'm really far away from the correct solution

Comment: Does this work for you? `print(s:match(".*:(.+)"))`

Comment: Thanks @lhf, I've used ESkri's solution but yours just came out useful for another (but similar) case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find last number in the string ignoring surrounded with colons:

```
s = "hello item:::::405498:::244405553::3405:34:405:59:::445:447:3205:::[test] and another 405 with test"
print(s:match".*%f[%d:](%d+)%f[^%d:]")  --> 405
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the last number, just iterate over all numbers and keep only the last one:

```lua
local s = "hello item:::::405498:::244405553::3405:34:405:59:::445:447:3205:::[test] and another 405 with test"
local last_num
for num in s:gmatch"%d+" do last_num = num end
```

If you want to get the largest `:`-free suffix of the string, a simple `match` will do:

```lua
-- Note: `or s` in case there is no `:`.
local last_part = s:match":(.-)$" or s
```

If you want more predictable (probably better) performance, use the pattern proposed by lhf.